# Cannot Create ODBC link to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, odbc

I am trying to create an ODBC Data Source.

I am using "With SQL Server authentication using a login ID and password entered by the user" and have entered my Login and password. The Login is visible in SQL Server Management Studio under Security-> Logins.

The login also contains the exact properties of the same login in my old server. When I hit next after entering the username and password I get:

Connection failed:
SQLState: '28000'
SQL Server Error: 18456
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'myUser'.

The server has been already set to "SQL Server and Windows Authentication Mode" I am still having problems connecting.

Any ideas or suggestions please

Answer (score 0):

1. Look at the default database of the Login that is failing and make sure that Login has permission to access it.
2. Look at the User that is mapped to the Login for the default database and make sure that User exists and is configured with the permissions/roles/memberships you need.